# Bridge between two cms

Tags: php

I want to code as a personnal project (i'm student) a bridge between two cms located in 2 differents servers and databases.

For example an e-commerce cms and an ERP : I want to synchronise only let's say the 'order' table.

But the table schema is not the same so I have to make a 'compatibility' script to update the right corresponding fields.
Let's say it's done and I can synchronise the 2 tables in both directions : I can add an order in the e-commerce table when a new order is written in the ERP table. And the same in the other direction.

But I need to execute my scripts to make this happen.
I can put the script in a cron job so it's executed at 18 pm, but I want the data to be synchronised in real time.

Which means when a new order is added in the ERP table, the e-commerce table on the other server is updated too. And the same thing in the other direction.

The only solution I found is to fire some events. When the ERP table is updated a script is launched and update the e-commerce table. When the e-commerce cms table is updated, a script is launched and update the ERP table.

But it needs two scripts : one in both sides... I want only a script in one of the side.

How can I achieve this ? Is there a way/ a process to sync them in real time, just by creating an application in one of both sides

Comment: Yeah, like we know what CMS you're using.  Did you read the FAQ?  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  It's not that long.  I recommend it.  Read it before posting here again.  Then, try posting again, and add details.  You can start by telling us what two CMSes you're using.  We're not mind readers, you know.

Comment: what about sqlsync ? http://silvercoders.com/en/products/sqlsync/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same database for the two CMS instances.

If you're not doing that (or using a semi-real-time database replication layer), then the only way to keep them in sync with low latency is event-based message passing like you describe in your post.

This does **not** have a zero latency - you don't have a transactional commit system, so there is a moment after one CMS does something and before the other sees it. Whether this will cause you issues depends on what your particular use case is.

Again, the right way to do this is to have two frontends sharing one backend.

Comment: If the other cms is coded in a different langage maybe I cannot code a plugin for it :D So maybe the right way to do this with only a script in one side, is to launch it every x hours for example. I don't need real real time, 1 hour latency is ok.

Comment: @flo31 An hour's latency is easy, running a synchronization script will do just fine. That's nowhere near "real time" - generally, "real time" means literally no delay. "near real time" is usually milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, in fact I wanted to know is there was a way to do it in real time. But just for my personnal knowledge. I use Joomla cms and I want to create a component that syncs some Joomla components and other cms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using two CMS written in different languages, then you could approach this by setting up a simple REST API for both CMS. So that when either CMS is updated a call is sent to the other CMS API with a request to update.

I'm not sure if you're using pre existing CMS or your rolling your own, but you should do a search for '[rest API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20rest%20api&submit=search)'

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of issues with what you're proposing that make it rather impractical. It appears that you want to syndicate content between two completely different CMS systems in REAL TIME. Each picking up an RSS from the other would handle the syndication (but you'd have to handle changes which were merely updates, so not just a case of inserting new content) however this isn't going to perform well in real time across servers.

The world is full of compromises, and I think you would have to first consider compromising on the requirement for "real time".....